# Paired t-test on a dataset containing multiple group variables

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, count-data, poisson-regression

I am analyzing data from a bacterial growth experiment.  In my experiment, I have different growth condition. For every growth condition, I have measured the bacterial number at day0, Day1, Day2, Day3, Day7 and Day14. So my main objective is to see the significant difference in bacterial count between Day0 and other days (Day0 ~ Day1, Day2, Day3, Day7, Day14) in different experimental condition.

[image]

In my data set (example image), all experimental condition are listed in column B (Temperature), C (Experiment), D (Swab), and E (Swab). The F column contains subsequent number of Day (0 to 7, I treat them as factor variable).  And the column G is the measure variable (count of bacteria).

For all experimental condition, I would like to compare the “logcfu” value of Day0 to to all subsequent day (each growth condition are independent, I am not going to compare the condition). 
For example,
(i) compare (t-test) the “logcfu” between **Day0 and Day1** of ‘RT’ temperature, ‘A’ experiment, ‘T1’ swab, ‘low’ inoculum.
(ii)    compare (t-test) the “logcfu” between **Day0 and Day2** of ‘RT’ temperature, ‘A’ experiment, ‘T1’ swab, ‘low’ inoculum.
(iii)   compare (t-test) the “logcfu” between **Day0 and Day3** of ‘RT’ temperature, ‘A’ experiment, ‘T1’ swab, ‘low’ inoculum.
…………..so on.

I can get summery measures by using following formula, which gives me a nice summary containing all results in single table.

```
data <- read.csv("alllogcfu.csv",  sep = ";", dec = ",")
str(data)
data$day <- as.factor(data$day)
library(Rmisc)
summarydata <- summarySE(cfudata, measurevar="logCFU", groupvars=c("swab", "temperature", "inoculum", "experiment", "day"))
```

My question-
Is there any way to do t.test using a single command so that I will get all t statistics value for all experiment condition in a single table?
Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 3):

From what you described the bacterial counts across days within experimental conditions are correlated, which may call for a more general longitudinal/repeated measures/serial data analysis that does not need to assume that differences in counts or difference in log counts have the correct statistical properties for subtraction to be valid (e.g., equal variance assumption, flat relationship between the difference and the baseline count).  I would think of this not as a "compare all with baseline" but rather as "characterize the time trends in counts and compute confidence bands for time-response profiles and differences in profiles across experimental conditions."  You might entertain a mixed effects Poisson regression.  Time trends can be modeled with a quadratic function of time.

Comment: Dear Frank Harrell, Thank you very much for your recommendation.